# Can't connect to AWS postsql RDS

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to stand up a Dev database for a web app. I have setup the Dev database using a snapshot from the current prod server. I'm currently trying to restore the dev server's DB from a .dmp file I have via:

`psql --host=blahblahblahblah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=postgres --password --dbname <dbname> -f backup.sql`

Which gives me the error:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "awseb-e-gjem7uperk-stack-awsebrdsdatabase-1hzzq9r4a74c.cg7ksxih0nnz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (3.225.21.170), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I believe I have followed all the [recommended steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html) to debug.

1. Check that the host name used is the DB instance endpoint and that the port number used is correct - yes, they are correct. I copied directly from the RDS Connectivity & security page.
2. Make sure that the DB instance's public accessibility is set to Yes:

[image]

3. Make sure that the user connecting to the database has CONNECT access to it - (**THIS ONE I'M NOT SURE ABOUT** How can I do this if I can't connect?)
4. Check that the security group assigned to the DB instance has rules to allow access - I have access to everybody. I know it's not best practice, but I'm trying to get it to work right now

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what is causing me to not connect?

**EDIT:**

You can see my VPC/Internet gateway connection here:

[image]

See subnet connected to VPC group:

[image]

I also added a new group to allow all traffic, but still not working:

[image]

See subnet routing here:

[image]

See Routes here:

[image]

ACL looks fine too:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to access this database through a database viewer tool such as DBeaver Community Edition or Postico (if you are using a mac) ?

Comment: Make sure you allow IPv6 IP addresses as well. i.e. `::/0`

Comment: You have a ton of subnets configured with RDS there. Do all of those subnets actually have a route to your VPC's Internet Gateway? You need to make sure the database is only deploying in public subnets if you want it to be publicly accessible.

Comment: How can I do that? I posted an edit showing my VPC/internet gateway relationship as well as subnet to VPC. I also added`::/0` to the allow list. Those subnets just came stock when I created the DB. I'm new to dev ops, so I'm piece a lot of this together through documentation/trial and error. Thank you!

Comment: @ArunT yes I have. I cannot connect on DBeaver w/ error "connection attempt timed out"

Comment: Even if i set a custom rule allowing all TCP traffic (0.0.0.0 w/ ports 0-9999) I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was my subnets. [This](https://repost.aws/questions/QUPuPeGpvyS7ONsHOGGZXJDA#ANMqWLHSocRUu6HvXX9Rt4UA) was the answer from an AWS re:Post form:

By the looks of the screenshots in your stackoverflow post, the instance has been recovered into a subnet group with 12 subnets. But the routing table only has six subnets associated with it.

I did this by going to my VPC -> the routing table -> Subnet Association Tab -> Edit Subnet Association -> add required subnets (I just added them all)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have Internet Gateway attached to your VPC.